# Convergence of $z_n = i+\left(\frac{2+3i}{5}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I need to analyze the convergence of

$$z_n = i+\left(\frac{2+3i}{5}\right)^n$$

I tried to see $2+3i$ as $\sqrt{13}(\cos \theta_0 + i\sin\theta_0)$ and then we'd have:

$$z_n = i+\frac{1}{5^n}\sqrt{13}(\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta)$$

The real part is: $\frac{1}{5^n}\sqrt{13}(\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta)$ which is a product of a bounded function and one that goes to $0$, then can I say that the real part goes to $0$ and then:

$$\lim z_n = i$$

?

Comment: The real part is not $\frac{1}{5^n}\sqrt{13}(\cos n\theta + i\sin n\theta)$, but $\frac{1}{5^n}\sqrt{13}(\cos n\theta)$.

Comment: Your reasoning for why the second term tends to $0$ is correct, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\mid z_n -i \mid = \left| \frac{2+3i}{5}\right|^n = \sqrt{(4+9)/25}^n \rightarrow 0.$$